Invalid Grant error with code flow Keycloak
I ran keycloak in a docker container using this command (I've tried version 24 as well)
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0 start-dev

When I go to the url
http://localhost:8080/realms/my_app/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/&client_id=my_app

I get an authorization code, immediately after i use postman to make a request to get a token
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/realms/my_app/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  -d 'client_id=my_app' \
  -d 'redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/' \
  -d 'code= {codeFromUrlEntered}'

however i keep getting the error:
error="invalid_code", grant_type="authorization_code", code_id="594c3aa2-cec6-488d-8026-24b9fb6721e5", client_auth_method="client-secret"

I can confirm its the first time i use the authorization code.
Another notes: The clientId and Realm name is the same.
The reason I used google is because its an easy public URL that anyone can use to recreate the issue, I'm not using this in my actual application.

It looks like there were a few misunderstandings in the configuration.
#1 There seems to be confusion between the realm and the client ID. You've set the client_id as my_app, which actually refers to the realm in the URL http://localhost:8080/realms/my_app. The client_id should correspond to the client identifier, not the realm name.
#2 The redirect_uri has been set to https://www.google.com/. For security and functionality, the redirect_uri should align with the URL of your local server or your production environment, not to an unrelated site like google.com.
#3 The Authorization Code Flow (grant_type=authorization_code) requires a user login step; hence, using cURL directly for this process is not feasible. This flow necessitates the provision of a local server to handle the code exchange through a redirect URL.
Demo
Launching Keycloak
By docker compose in here
Setting realm / client
Realm: my_app

Client: my_client

Client Secret

Create user
Credential
username: user1
password: 1234


Get token URL


"authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my_app/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
"token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/my_app/protocol/openid-connect/token",

Server
Save as server.js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID = "my_client";
const KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET = "oCDrud4nUSxp6ol56u9ZEJhdG3tsKji9"; // your client secret
const KEYCLOAK_REALM = "my_app";
const KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080";
const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000/callback"; // your client's redirect URI

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  const authUrl = `${KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=${encodeURIComponent(KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID)}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI)}&response_type=code&scope=openid`;
  res.redirect(authUrl);
});

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`, new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code,
    }), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });

    const { access_token, refresh_token, id_token } = response.data;
    // Here you can store/use the tokens as needed
    res.json({ access_token, refresh_token, id_token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.toString() });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Install dependencies
npm install express axios

Running server
node server.js

User login
Open the Browser and access this URL.
http://localhost:3000/login


Credential
username: user1
password: 1234

Result
Will display tokens in Browser


Thanks for the answer, in the example above i named my clientid and realm same. I want to use code flow so I need the authorization code. Also the reason I used Google.com is so that it appends the authorization code to googles url and google is a public website that won't use the authorization code so I should be able to use the auth code that is appended it to get a token. but as said before it gives the invalid grant error.
I also used google so that its easier to recreate the issue if anyone tries and they dont need to run a localhost instance
I'll edit my question to be more clear

You have control over your local development environment, including localhost. This means you can safely receive and handle the authorization code without exposure to third parties. In contrast, you do not control https://google.com, and so you cannot ensure the secure handling of the authorization code, nor can you access it once it's sent there.  Since you cannot register https://google.com/callback as a redirect URI for your application (because you don't own Google), it's both a violation of protocol and a security risk.

Google isn't being used in my actual application it was just for demonstration purposes so that it is easy to create. Yes I do have control over local host but I wanted an easy way for others to recreate the example without needing to spin up a localhost application. Although my application won't use localhost in the future and would be used in a production application
